# Is the action of free self-distributive algebras on racks computable in polynomial time?

Tags: braid-groups, quandles, yang-baxter-equations, self-distributivity

Let $B_{\infty}$ denote the infinite strand braid group. Let
$\mathrm{sh}:B_{\infty}\rightarrow B_{\infty}$ be the mapping where
$\mathrm{sh}(\sigma_{i})=\sigma_{i+1}$ whenever $i\geq 1$. Then
$B_{\infty}$ can be endowed with an operation $*$ known as shifted conjugacy where $*$ is defined by $$x*y=x\cdot\mathrm{sh}(y)\sigma_{1}\mathrm{sh}(x)^{-1}.$$ Then $*$ satisfies the self-distributivity identity $$x*(y*z)=(x*y)*(x*z).$$

A rack is an algebra $(X,*,*^{-1})$ that satisfies the following identities:

1. $x*(y*z)=(x*y)*(x*z)$ and
2. $x*(x*^{-1}y)=x*^{-1}(x*y)=y$.

A function $T:X^{2}\rightarrow X^{2}$ is said to satisfy the Yang-Baxter equation if 
$$(1_{X}\times T)\circ(T\times 1_{X})\circ(1_{X}\times T)=(T\times 1_{X})\circ(1_{X}\times T)\circ(T\times 1_{X}).$$

For example, if $(X,*,*^{-1})$ is a rack and $T(x,y)=(x*y,x)$, then $T$ always satisfies the Yang-Baxter equation.

If $T:X^{2}\rightarrow X^{2}$ satisfies the Yang-Baxter equation, then define
an action of $B_{n}$ on $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ by letting
$$(x_{1},\dots,x_{n},)\cdot \sigma_{i}
=(x_{1},\dots,x_{i-1},T(x_{i},x_{i+1}),x_{i+2},\dots,x_{n}).$$

Suppose that $X$ is a finite set and $T:X^{2}\rightarrow X^{2}$ is a bijective function that satisfies the Yang-Baxter equations. Then is the function
$$(x_{1},...,x_{k},t,a_{1},...,a_{n})\mapsto(x_{1},...,x_{k})\cdot t(a_{1},...,a_{n})$$
where $a_{1},...,a_{n}\in B_{\infty},x_{1},...,x_{k}\in X$, and $t$ is a term in the language of self-distributive algebras necessarily computable in polynomial time? What about the special case when $T(x,y)=(x*y,x)$ for some rack $(X,*,*^{-1})$ or when we restrict our case to when $t$ is a term in only one variable?

Comment: Why is there someone going around and downvoting everything that I post on this site?

Comment: Someone is going around and looking for questions that I have with zero upvotes just to downvote them even though these questions are of a very high quality.